# Is it possible to generate time without timzone with javascriptdatetimeconverter()

Tags: json.net

It serializes the date in this format:

```
"/Date(1667894400000-0800)/"
```

And I want it in this format like Microsoft's JavaScriptSerializer did:

```
"/Date(1667894400000)/"
```

Comment: Include your code in the post.

Comment: Are you referring to [`Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JavaScriptDateTimeConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.htm) from Json.NET?  If so, it doesn't output DateTime values in the `"/Date(1667894400000-0800)/"` format, it outputs in JavaScript constructor format (which is not strictly allowed by the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/)), e.g.: `{"dateTime":new Date(1667894400000)}`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEDRFi.

Comment: Since it's unlikely you are actually using this converter, please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] showing how you are currently serializing your DateTime values.  See also [ask].

Comment: You can get `"\/Date(1667894400000)\/"` by setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatHandling.htm), see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eh5XII.  Maybe that's what you are using?  If so, setting `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` should force your datetime values to be converted to UTC when serialized, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCW8YK.

Comment: It would also help to know the [`DateTime.Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=net-7.0) of the datetimes you are trying to serialize.  Is it `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own converter. After thinking more about it I thought why even have this complex `\/Date(1667894400000)\/` format from which I would have to regex parse the integer out on client to convert to JS date. Just returning an integer alone makes it much easier especially when the client knows the expected type.

Now is there a built in flag in Json.net that does this? I don't know.

```
Public Class JsonDateWriteConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objType As Type) As Boolean
        Return objType Is GetType(Date)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        writer.WriteValue(New DateTimeOffset(value).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanRead As Boolean
        Get
            Return False  'converter ignored for Json deserialization
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objType As Type, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

End Class
```